# Proving that the sequence $a_{n + 2} = -2 \left( 2n^2 + 1 \right) a_n - a_{n - 2}$ is unbounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I came across this recurrence relation

$a_{n + 2} = -2 \left( 2n^2 + 1 \right) a_n - a_{n - 2}$

with $a_0, a_1 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$ to be taken arbitrary and $a_2 = - a_0, a_3 = -7a_1$. Then, from the very first terms of the recurrence relation, I can say that the sequence defined will be unbounded. However, I am unable to find a analytic proof for the same.

My idea is to just check the even subsequence and prove it to be unbounded so that the overall sequence also becomes unbounded.

Comment: It's false. Take the arbitrary choice $a_0, a_1 = 0$ and the sequence is bounded.

Comment: For both non zero. If they are both zero then the sequence is trivially zero.

Comment: Start by noting that the sequence is defined entirely in either even or odd terms, so you only need to analyse it once, and the analysis then applies for both $a_0$ and $a_1$.  Then prove that the sequence is alternating (i.e $a_{2n+4} = +c_0a_{2n+2}$ and $a_{2n+2} = -c_1a_{2n}$.  Then show that those constants grow without bound (in fact they grow as $n$ grows)

Comment: I am stuck exactly in "proving" this. I have already made these observations for a few terms.

Comment: Is it monotone?

Comment: No. It cannot be. The terms alternate in sign.

Comment: Aren't the even or odd terms separately monotone?

Comment: The odd and the even terms constitute independent sequences that could benefit from a separate analysis.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Notice that the odd and even terms as separate sequences also alternate in sign. This is because of $- 2 \left( n^2 + 1 \right)$, which makes the sign opposite.

Comment: @JeanMarie I know! But, I am not able to "write" the proof for any of them. That is the reason I asked the questions. All observations regarding the absolute value and unboundedness are already made by me earlier. I just wanted a "textbook" proof which Mathematically explains the fact.

Comment: I was able to, finally, see that.

Comment: I'm wondering if we took every other term (of, say, the even terms), we could prove that sequence is monotone, and then, if it's bounded,  get a limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The odd and the even terms constitute independent sequences deserving a separate analysis.

Let us consider the even case.

The given relationship with $n=2m$ becomes

$$a_{2m+2}=-2(8m^2+1)a_{2m}-a_{2m-2}$$

Setting $u_m:=a_{2m}$, we get :

$$u_{m+1}=-2(8m^2+1)u_{m}-u_{m-1}\tag{1}$$

Said otherwise :

$$\dfrac12 (u_{m+1}+u_{m-1})=-(8m^2+1)u_{m}\tag{2}$$

As the LHS of (2) is the midpoint of $u_{m+1}$ and $u_{m-1}$, by an immediate recurrence, we see the sequence $u_m$ is alternate. Taking $v_n:=(-1)^n u_n=|u_n|$, we get the equivalent recursion **with all positive terms** :

$$v_{m+1}=2(8m^2+1)v_{m}-v_{m-1}, \ \text{with} \ v_0=v_1=a_0$$

or

$$v_{m+1}=(16m^2+1)v_{m}+(v_m-v_{m-1})\tag{3}$$

Set apart the first term, (3) shows, here also by an immediate recurrence, that sequence $(v_n)$ is increasing.

Two cases : either this sequence converges to a limit $L<+\infty$, either it is unbounded. The first hypothesis cannot hold when we take $n\to \infty$ in (3) : we would get $L$ on the LHS and $\infty$ on the RHS...

Comment: There is a flaw in my reasoning. I am going to correct it.

Comment: Flaw corrected through the use of an auxiliary sequence.

Answer (score 0):

What I can think is to express $a_n$ in terms of $a_0$. It should be the form $a_n = f(n)\cdot a_0$. If $f(n)$ is unbounded, then we are done.

The most complicated thing is to derive $f(n)$, though...

Comment: There is no reason that we can express $a_n = f(n)\cdot a_0$.

Comment: Since $a_2 = -a_0$ and $a_3 = -7a_1$, it is a reason. I also want to use the ratio test taught in calculus to prove this.

One more thing, how to justify the right hand side in the last equation of your proof is unbounded? Maybe $u_m$ can be arbitrarily small?

Comment: Interesting question, HAHA

Comment: Thanks for having pointed a flaw in my reasoning. I have changed it at the price of taking an auxiliary sequence.